# permissions to show members list to members of group [using ejabberd,xmpp,muc]

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, muc

I am working on a xmpp group chat. I am able to create group, chat invitation n all other things.
when I try to get members list it shows list of members to group owner only, not to the group members.

here is my muc access rules:

```
{access, muc_admin, [{allow, admin}]}.
{access, muc, [{allow, all}]}.
```

and my mod_muc configurations:

```
{mod_muc,      [
              {host, "conference.@HOST@"},
              {access, muc},
              {access_create, muc},
              {access_persistent, muc},
              {access_admin,muc_admin},
              {history_size, 80},
              {max_users, 400},
              {default_room_options,
                    [
                      {max_users, 400},
                      {allow_change_subj, true},
                      {allow_query_users, true},
                      {allow_private_messages, true},
                      {allow_user_invites, true},
                      {anonymous, true},
                      {logging, true},
                      {members_by_default, true},
                      {persistent, true},
                      {members_only, true},
                      {public_list, false}
                    ]}
              ]},
```

am I doing something wrong in my configuration.
need help as soon as possible,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"MUC members list" is an administrative list, it is *not* a list of currently presented members, administrator can add there any user and assign them a moderator role or ban permanently, even if this user never touch this muc.
To show actual users list you must track presence packets you receiving when users join and leave muc room

Comment: so can you help that , what should I check next to show group members to group member? are my configurations for mod_muc correct on server? do I need to check anything client side?